# Geodesic confluence as witness to a local extrinsic bound

Tags: riemannian-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

This problem seeks a relationship between the lengths of geodesics
which emanate from a point on a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then
come together again, and the bounds on the lengths of centred normal
fibres through them in a maximal tubular neighbourhood of the surface.

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth closed (compact without
boundary) surface. The *local reach* is a function $\rho: S
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\rho(x)$ is the radius of the
smaller of the two maximal empty tangential balls on either side of
$S$ at $x$. An empty tangential ball at $x$ is an open Euclidean ball
in $B \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ that does not intersect $S$, and whose
boundary sphere is tangent to $S$ at $x$. It is maximal if it is not
contained in any other such ball.

Let $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ be two geodesics which emanate from $p \in
S$ in distinct directions and then meet again at $q \in S$.

> I wish to show that there exists some point $z$ on either $\alpha$ or
>   $\gamma$ such that
>   $$ 
> > \rho(z) \leq \frac{\ell(\alpha) + \ell(\gamma)}{2\pi},
> > $$
>   where $\ell(\alpha)$ is the length of $\alpha$.

If for example $\alpha$ were the shorter geodesic and it contained a
point conjugate to $p$, then our bound would follow from a standard
result that relates the length of $\alpha$ to a bound on the square
root of the sectional curvature it sees (the local reach is bounded by
the radii of the osculating balls).

Also, if $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ together form a geodesic loop, then the
result follows by considering the curvature of that loop as a space
curve ( ... I asked for [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741/a-good-lower-bound-on-the-maximum-curvature-in-a-loop) with that too).

These two observations allow us to show that at least somewhere within
a geodesic disk centred at $p$ and of radius bounded by the
injectivity radius at $p$, we can find a $z$ satisfying the
inequality, but I want more. I want to find such a $z$ on one of these
two arbitrary geodesics.

This question came up within the context of surface sampling, where a
popular means of defining the sampling density is through a function
that is bounded by the local reach. We worked around it, but I'm still
curious, and hope it might provide insight.